# How to start 1:1 conversation with user by sending OAuthPrompt

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using Bot Framework v4 and c# to build a teams bot that signs in user when added to channel.

My use case, is that each time a new user is added to the channel, I want to send him an OAuthPrompt in 1:1 in order to sign him in.

The samples provided for proactive message shows only how to send a simple message, and can't find the right resources to solve this problem.

Comment: have you looked into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample and https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth?